# Inertiajs Some components are accessing only with <LINK> but when I try to access directly it gives error 500 without any response

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

On my local machine it works normally, but when I try to add to the server it behaves this way, it is only accessing a few components with  when I try to access direct link comes the error 500 without any vsing to browser or browser console.

Comment: 500 error means a server side error. Start by checking the php error log file

Answer (score 1):

I already checked the logs but did not help. I was able to solve the problem.
In my vite configuration file I commented on this. It seems that files have a problem after building the production project:

```
  Laravel ({
         Input: [
             //'Apppreact/admin/app.tsx ',
             'APPREACT/MAIN/APP.TSX',
             'APPREACT/TEACHER/APP.TSX',
             'APPREACT/INFORMADE/APP.TSX',
             'APPREACT/STUDENT/APP.TSX',
             'APPREACT/ACCOUNT/APP.TSX',
         ],
         Refresh: False,
         Builddirectory: "JS",
         publicdirectory: "public",
     }),
```

Comment: Did the error come back someone please help?